# Отклонение полезных тревог

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Недавно произошёл интересный случай. Кажется, тревога была полезной, но всё же отклонена:

> [image]

Это новичок ♦ так неожиданно себя повёл или есть какие-то тайные модераторские алгоритмы, объясняющие, что принять, а что отклонить? Что-то помешало оформить эту тревогу в качестве полезной? Синоним был утверждён при этом.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это был я. Отклонял, т.к. принятие тревоги как "полезной" ведёт к выдаче минуса целевому сообщению от `Духа сообщества`. А вопрос этого, вроде, не заслуживает.

Думаю, в данном случае надо было не тревогу ставить, но написать модераторам в чате, например. Ну или создать вопрос на мете с предложением голосовать за синонимизацию меток - так и модераторов не пришлось бы задействовать)

**UPD**

Согласно @Nick Volynkin

> Так не со всеми тревогами, только «низкого качества» и «не ответ».

Выходит, вышла ошибка. В следующий раз тревогу "полезной" отмечу)

Comment: Я знаю, что это Вы :) Причина ясна теперь. Но это кажется глупым поведением Духа, ибо тревога «требуется вмешательство модератора» не должна значить, что сообщение плохое. А чат не подходит по разным причинам: 1. кое-кто там уже не пингабельный; 2. некоторые модераторы против использования чата в качестве уведомлений о проблемах; 3. чат заполонили тошнотные флагальщики и кое-кто с ними соглашается.

Comment: @alexolut, на самом деле я точно не знаю как дух минусует. Возможно, в данном случае, он и не стал бы минус ставить... Но я решил не рисковать) Давайте попробуем позвать человека, который наверняка знает `будет ли минус на вопрос от духа поставлен в случае принятия тревоги типа "требуется вмешательство модератора"`

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky ^^^

Comment: Вообще-то, а Вы уверены насчет описанного поведения Духа? На Мете я часто флагаю сообщения с просьбой поставить красную метку, тревога признается полезной, но сообщение минуса не получает. Это поведение Меты иное, или Вы всё же заблуждаетесь?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Дедушка Мороз, Выходи! cc//Nicolas Chabanovsky

Comment: Надеюсь главный по [meta-tag:модераторский-произвол] нас рассудит)

Comment: Так не со всеми тревогами, только «низкого качества» и «не ответ».