# Отклонение тревоги с просьбой очевидной синонимизации меток

Tags: поддержка, синонимы-меток, тревоги, модераторский-произвол

Недавно [выяснилось](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350461/1351198#comment2397932_1351198), что одновременно существуют метки [c++20](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) (латинская `c`) и [с++20](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%2b%2b20) (русская `с`). Очевидно, что их стоит синонимизировать, как это было сделано в своё время для меток с указанием предыдущих стандартов языка: см. список синонимов для [c++11](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), [c++14](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) и [c++17](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). Вообще, из-за совпадения начертания латинской `c` и русской `с`, да ещё и расположения на одной и той же клавише клавиатуры подобные казусы случаются постоянно. И список подобных синонимов на самом деле даже несколько шире:

> [image: си-нонимы]

К сожалению, система добавления синонимов обычными пользователями на сайте далека от совершенства. Я даже второй раз к ряду решился объявить конкурс на MSE на вопрос с предложением вынести процедуру синонимизации в очереди проверок: [Give Tag synonyms their own review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202754/339911). А в случае с [c++20](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) у меня даже не оказалось достаточного рейтинга по метке, чтобы инициировать процедуру синонимизации штатными средствами.

В связи с этим, я поставил кастомную тревогу для модератора на [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350461/1351198#comment2397932_1351198) с просьбой синонимизировать упомянутые метки. Подобный канал общения с модераторами ранее [воспринимался достаточно адекватно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6620/176217). Однако, модератор тревогу отклонил без какого бы то ни было описания причины такого решения. Думаю, ну может хотя бы метки всё же объединил. Бывали такие случаи, когда тревога отклонялась, но фактически предложение выполнялось. Но здесь тоже, к сожалению, ничего не произошло.

Хотелось бы узнать, кто из модераторов так странно себя повёл и почему не считает очевидным благом для сайта объединение упомянутых меток. Не теряю надежды, что у него просто дрогнула рука и мышка кликнула не туда, а потом что-то отвлекло внимание и про синонимизацию тоже забыл. Хотя  последнее тоже не особо можно назвать действием, которое следовало бы отнести к качественной модерации.

Comment: Ну почему на комментарии-то, да ещё и к ответу, а не на вопросе??? PS: Отклонил не я.

Comment: @Qwertiy а чем плох комментарий, тем более, что в нём весь контекст ситуации описан?

Comment: Я некоторое время следил за упомянутым вами [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1350461). И даже предлагал некоторое решение в комментарии к вопросу... Но сейчас ни моего комментария, ни некоторых комментариев от других пользователей (например, от [user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670) с пояснением, что по стандарту работоспособность предложенных вариантов не гарантируется) там просто нет.  Т.е. их нет ни под вопросом, ни в чате, видимо они были просто удалены.

Comment: С таким агрессивным подходом к удалению комментариев я почему-то совершенно не удивлён, что удалятор не видит разницы: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBEiJ.png) и [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKXaG.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отклонил тревогу, потому что не увидел разницы ни в самих ссылках тегов, ни на страницах информации о тегах.

Сейчас синоним создан и объединён.

```
updating post history, 26 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 19 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 19 rows affected
destroying 'с++20': [с++20] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 47
tag remapping of [c++20] and [с++20] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
6 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: Если разницы не видно, это ещё не значит, что её нет! Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, имелось ввиду, что выглядела как одна и та же страница, как будто уже все на одну страницу ведет